# How to use an application installed from my office PC in my home PC without the use of Remote Desktop Sofware?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have an office PC connected to a LAN through a wired connection which enables me to use a certain program. This wired cable has no internet connection and its only purpose is for the use of the said application.

Also, my office PC has a wireless adapter that enables me to connect to the internet. I want to use the said application that is linked to a LAN-wired connection in my home PC by the use of a Wi-Fi connection.

I don't want to use a remote desktop application because there is another user on my office PC when I'm out of the office.

What recommendations/ideas might help me in this kind of setting?

Comment: There is no solution to your problem since you have eliminated the only possible solution.

Comment: This is a question to ask company IT. Trying a work-around suggested by a third party would be a good way to lose one's job, and possibly be blacklisted, for violating policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it runs on another system but shows up on your computer, that pretty much always *is* some form of "remote desktop". I don't think I've ever seen the opposite mechanism (that is, .exe files "running" locally but being magically redirected to use remote hardware), only heard of it having existed decades ago.

*The* 'Remote Desktop' feature (as built into Windows) is not inherently limited to one user per machine; that's more of a *licensing* imposed limit, but the actual Terminal Services subsystem is very much designed to support concurrent logins by multiple users. (That is, assuming you and the other person are using different Windows accounts!)

…Unfortunately there is no official way to actually permit multi-user usage on "client" editions of Windows (that is, Pro/Enterprise), i.e. no add-on that can be bought; it's only Windows Server that allows this. (There are third-party patches to bypass the single-user limit, but it's probably not the best idea to use them on company systems?)

So your only choices are a) Windows RDP and have the other person use a separate computer, or b) Windows RDP and deal with the licensing somehow (either by using Windows Server on your workstation or by hacking Windows 10/11, neither of which are great options).

(Third-party remote desktop solutions that do not integrate with Terminal Services probably have no hopes of achieving this at all, as they're pretty much limited to mirroring the console display.)